# How do i use native rest api in Django frame work?

Tags: python, django

I am a GUI developer. I have server-side code which will provide me a REST API that will return only JSON. So using this native rest API I have to write a code in existing project based on the Django framework to show the GUI part.

My rest API is like `http://<ip>:8080/wm/core/controller/switches/json`. This API will give the list of switches that i want to show on GUI using Django. There is one possibility to call API from JavaScript to function in `view.py` file that will return the JSON to a JavaScript file and manipulate it data using JavaScript. Is it possible?

How do I call these native rest APIs using Django GUI and design the view of GUI?

Comment: It's unclear to me what do you want to achieve. Do you want to use a Django view as a proxy for the json file, say to modify the responde before sending it to the javascript code? i.e. why you cannot call the API directly from javascript?

Comment: I have one project developed in Django web framework so I have to integrate one external module into this project using 3rd party REST API. How do i implement in Django?

Comment: Still unclear - really you should show us some code or some details on what exactly you want to do with that API. Do you need to "use" the results of a REST query inside your django code or the result have to be transmitted "as is" to the javascript code rendered by your view?

Comment: I need to "use" the results of a REST query inside your django code in view.py and process that json data then it render to html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `urllib2.urlopen` function to submit your request to the REST server and get the response:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://acme.com:8080/wm/core/controller/switches/json'
params = urllib.urlencode({
  'firstName': 'John',
  'lastName': 'Doe'
})
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params).read() # a POST request
```

then, eventually, parse the json file in order to generate your GUI

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

data = json.loads(response)
pprint(data)
```

relevant documentation: [urllib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) and [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json)

Comment: Thanks furins... I will implement this in my project and reply you

Comment: sure, let me know if it's unclear or if the answer does not solve your  doubts.